# I'm trying to get a button to show filtered results in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, filter, display

I am trying to create a fake website.  It is currently riddled with errors.  Please ignore those for now.  They are irrelevant for now.

On the 'Available Dogs' page (Dogs2Choose.html), I have 3 different buttons to display the available male dogs, but none of them work.

I get no error message, but I also get no response when I hit the buttons.  I tried a bunch of different ways to do this from examples on JavaScript, but nothing has worked.  Please help!

(I am new to this, so please be patient and use small words).

.... I tried using '.where', '.filter', '.forEach', '.forEvery', but nothing has worked so far.

please see below here for the codes . . .

Button 1:
Dogs2Choose.html:

```
    <p id="Result">Click button to see Male Dogs</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="MaleDogFunction(DogArray)">Choose Male Dogs </button>
```

Adoption.JS:

```
  const DogArray = [
       {PetName: "Boris", Gender: "Male", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Laborador"}, 
       {PetName: "Lucy", Gender: "Female", Age: "Puppy", Breed: "Golden Retriever"}, 
    ]
    const Result = DogArray.filter(MaleDogFunction);
    function MaleDogFunction(DogArray)  // not sure what goes here
    {
       return Gender = "Male"; //where gender = male;
    }
```

Button 2:
Dogs2Choose.html:

```
    <p id="result2">Button 2 </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="search(users)">stackoverflow example</button>
```

Adoption.JS:

```
    var users = [
      {name: 'Boris', gender: 'Male', Age: 'Senior', Breed: 'Chocolate Laborador'},
      {name: 'Lucy', gender: 'Female', Age: 'Puppy', Breed: 'Golden Retriever'}];

    var query = {gender: "Male"};
    var result2 = users.filter(search, query); 
    var element = document.getElementById('result2');
    
    function search(user){
      return Object.keys(this).every((key) => user[key] === this[key]);
    };
```

Here is the link to my GitHub site.
https://github.com/mflanner1982/PetAdoptionWebsite/commits?author=mflanner1982

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which I hope will get you going.

I have a function to display an array of dogs.
There's also two functions which created a filtered array of dogs.

The buttons either (0) display the whole array or (1) create a new array of dogs with the same gender, before displaying that new array.

I've used the `Object.keys` trick to get a list of all the fields that an object has - this saves me explicitly asking for name, gender, age & breed
I then loop through this array and extract the object's value for each of these keys, before creating a div and setting the visible text to be the value.

This also has the advantage of continuing to work if you add or remove a field from each animal. For instance, you might wish to add colour or temperament.

You don't need the dogT(ype) class. I've used it out of habit and to make the declaration of the `dogArray` variable cleaner

```js
"use strict";

function newEl(tag) {
  return document.createElement(tag)
}

function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

class dogT {
  constructor(name = null, gender = null, age = null, breed = null) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.breed = breed;
  }
}

const dogArray = [
  new dogT('Boris', 'Male', 'Senior', 'Labrador'),
  new dogT('Lucy', 'Female', 'Puppy', 'Golden Retriever')
];


function onLoaded(evt) {
  byId('allBtn').addEventListener('click', showAll, false);
  byId('fBtn').addEventListener('click', showFemale, false);
  byId('mBtn').addEventListener('click', showMale, false);
}



function showAll(evt) {
  showDogArray(dogArray);
}

function showMale(evt) {
  let inputArray = dogArray.filter((curDog) => curDog.gender == 'Male');
  showDogArray(inputArray);
}

function showFemale(evt) {
  let inputArray = dogArray.filter((curDog) => curDog.gender == 'Female');
  showDogArray(inputArray);
}

function showDogArray(inputArray) {
  let tgt = byId('output');
  tgt.innerHTML = '';

  inputArray.forEach(
    curDog => {
      let container = newEl('div');

      let keys = Object.keys(curDog);
      keys.forEach(
        curKey => {
          let div = newEl('div');
          div.textContent = curDog[curKey];
          container.appendChild(div);
        }
      );
      tgt.appendChild(container);
    }
  )
}
```

```css
#output>div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='controls'>
  <button id='allBtn'>Show all</button> | <button id='fBtn'>Show females</button> | <button id='mBtn'>Show males</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help!  (P.S. sorry for the late response)